# What is the purpose of appending "(0)" to this closure function?

Tags: javascript

As the title states, what is the purpose of appending `(0);` rather than just `();` in this code snippit ([found here](https://github.com/thomseddon/node-oauth2-server/blob/master/lib/runner.js)):

```
function runner (fns, context, next) {
  var last = fns.length - 1;

  (function run(pos) {
    fns[pos].call(context, function (err) {
      if (err || pos === last) return next(err);
      run(++pos);
    });
  })(0);
}
```

Comment: Because the function takes an argument. `0` is passed in for `pos`.

Comment: its trying to do a loop here, recursively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is approximately equivalent to:

```
function runner (fns, context, next) {
  var last = fns.length - 1;

  function run(pos) {
    fns[pos].call(context, function (err) {
      if (err || pos === last) return next(err);
      run(++pos);
    });
  }

  run(0);
}
```

`0` is just what’s passed to `run()` as the first value of `pos` – same as in the recursive `run(++pos);` (which would be better written as `run(pos + 1)`).

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is that you're passing 0 as the value to the *pos* argument.